# Uncaught Reference Error JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $containerHeight = $('.container').height();
        if ($containerHeight < 760) {
            $('.footer').css({
                position: 'static',
                bottom: 'auto',
                left: 'auto'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And I get the very unhelpful error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>   (anonymous function)

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You probably haven't included jQuery before running your own code.

Comment: Make sure your path to jquery library is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't included jQuery before running your own code.  Make sure you put this before your own `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```